# In a CDI Passivation Capable bean, is it possible to have non-passivation capable dependencies be re-injected rather than passivated?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld, openwebbeans

In a CDI Passivation Capable bean, is it possible to have non-passivation capable dependencies be re-injected rather than passivated?

Consider this code:

```
@SessionScoped
public class UserData implements Serializable {
  @Inject
  private Logger log;
  private String data;
}


@ApplicationScoped
public class LoggerFactory {
  @Produces
  public Logger getLogger(){
  ...
  }
}

public class Logger {
...
}
```

So `Logger` is *not* `Serializable`, but I really don't care. When `UserData` is deserialized, is it possible to have the producer for `Logger` called again somehow?

## EDIT

The original discussion started here:

http://www.cdi-spec.org/news/2015/07/03/CDI-2_0-EDR1-released/#comment-2119769909

Hoping the CDI Expert group comes up with a better way than `@Instance`

Comment: A lot of reasons... What if you're injecting an EJB? Does it have to be serializable as well? What about SFL4J? Logger does not extend Serializable.

Comment: CDI and EJB generate and inject serializable proxies delegating further to the currently available (and auto-created) instance on a per-thread basis. Or did you face a `NotSerializableException`?

Comment: CDI complains at boot time that some of the injected dependencies are not passivation capable. Which seems ridiculous since it's creating proxies for them!

Comment: Never faced those with Weld.

Comment: :( What version of weld are you running? I'm using TomEE which is OWB and I think CDI 1.0

Comment: EJB has a @PostActivate method annotation that does the trick. Isn't there a CID equivalent?

Comment: @BalusC, that's why: Some beans initialize non-serializable fields base on data on @Injected fields, and this is done in the `@PostConstruct` method. We want to do that post-activation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#passivating_scope), you have your answer. `Logger` is not serializable, so the bean of type `Logger` is not passivation capable. The container doesn't provide the trick you are requesting.

The solution would be to write something like that:

```
@SessionScoped
public class UserData implements Serializable {
  @Inject
  private Instance<Logger> logInstance;
  private String data;

  public Logger getLog() {
   return logInstance.get();
  }
}
```

Ans use `getLog()` instead of `log` in your code.

Comment: Why doesn't the container provide a serializable proxy? (Like it does for nearly everything else)